# Email Signature

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I have multiple domains on Google Apps. I want to incorporate corporate email signature for all users. Can this be done via the admin panel? If yes, how can it be done and if not, what are the alternatives to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want all users in your domain to have the same signature?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your edition of Google Apps. Here is what described on the [Google Support webpage](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176652):

- **Google Apps (free edition)**: You can't, but your users can add their own signatures.
- **Google Apps for Education and Business**: Yes. You can use the Google Email Settings API to programmatically update Gmail settings for multiple users.
- **Google Apps for Business**: Yes. In addition to the Google Email Settings API, you can also add automatic signatures for all of your users through the Postini Compliance Footer.

Answer (score 1):

Google have [integrated much of Postini into Google Apps for business](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1381105) now (as of January 2012) and many of the things that used require Postini to do can now be done within the Google control panel.

[Setting a domain-wide footer is explained here](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364576).

The gist of it is:

1. Go to Settings (tabs along the top.)
2. Email (down the left-hand side)
3. Filters (underneath the tabs bar that contains "Settings").
4. Click the "Add Setting" button (On the right-hand side.)
5. Choose "Append Footer (Left-hand side of the pop-up.)
6. Paste or type your footer in the text area.
7. Click the "Add Setting" button (at the bottom of the pop-up.)
8. Click the "Save Changes" button (at the bottom-left of the page.)

The link in JMax's answer showed up in Russian for me (Google said they're trying to fix that.) and the link in that document to Postini is now a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through Google Apps settings pages, there isn't a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a thing call "[Canned responses](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/10/new-in-labs-canned-responses.html)", account by account.

IMHO, not very useful, but may give you a hint.